# LINQ to SQL Partial method does not override auto generated method

Tags: c#, sql, linq, partial-methods

I am looking to get create a partial method to override an auto generated method in linq to sql.
From my reading i assume that my method should be used over the auto generated method. 
if that is the case why am i getting this error?
"Type X already defines a member called ZZZ with the same parameter types"

When i run the program the autogenerated method is used instead of my one.

```
 public partial class HospitalDataContext
{
     partial  void  DeleteHospitalStaff(HospitalStaff staffMember)
    {
        staffMember.Patients.ToList().ForEach(
            patient => DeletePatientCustom(patient.PatientID));

        DeleteStaff(staffMember.HospitalStaffID);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: I assume your auto generated method has an implementation. You can only use a partial method if the other method has no implementation, i.e. partial  void  DeleteHospitalStaff(HospitalStaff staffMember); Try overriding the method - override void  DeleteHospitalStaff(HospitalStaff staffMember){...}

Comment: The auto generated method has an implmentation                      private void DeleteHospitalStaff(HospitalStaff obj)
        {
            this.DeleteStaff(((System.Nullable<int>)        (obj.HospitalStaffID)));                                                      
        }

Comment: I tried to override the method and I still get the original error.